# Custom current_user devise + Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I have devise + a scaffold "house" created, and I want that a user only can edite your own house.

This is my **houses_controller:**

```
def authenticate_owner!
  @house = house.find(params[:id])
    if user_signed_in? && current_user.email == @house.user.email
      return true
    end
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "You must have permission to access this category."
      return false
    end
```

I have too this code in the top houses_controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_owner!
skip_before_filter :authenticate_owner! , :only => [:show, :index, :new]
```

but not working, always show the message:

**"You must have permission to access this category."**

how I can get the user who created the scaffold and compare it to the user who is registered?

Comment: the code you posted is not complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed :D The problem is @house = **house**.find(params[:id]), is: @house = **House**.find(params[:id])

Answer (score 1):

You need to put an else there.. you probably meant to write:

```
def authenticate_owner!
  @house = house.find(params[:id])
    if user_signed_in? && current_user.email == @house.user.email
      return true
    else
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "You must have permission to access this category."
      return false   # this will never be executed!!
    end
end
```